# RESTful : Best URI design between hierarchy and filter

Tags: rest, filter, uri, hierarchy

I have table log.. and inside that table I have some columns, there're id_log, user_role, log, timestamp, timer

the type of user_role is enum('guest','admin','moderator')

I already have 2 URIs :

```
/logs (to represent all logs)
```

and

```
/logs/id-{number} (to represent logs with specific id_log)
```

I know in URI design, / (slash) is used to represent a resource in a hierarchical relationship with the previous segment..

What is the best format to represent log with specific user role?

```
/logs/{role} (using role as hierarchy)
```

or

```
/logs?roll={role} (using role as filter)
```

Please give me an advice

Comment: Both `/logs/{role}` and `/logs?role=someValue` serves the same purpose. But, for me, the second approach seems more appropriate. In REST we talk about resource.

Comment: @Joshi : thanks Joshi.. it's clear now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In REST you need to separate out resources and parameters.  In your case the resource is, as you correctly state, a log and identifies an entity and so this should form part of the URL.  Filtering the log is not something which defines the resource you are obtaining, so should be a parameter to the request.

Consider the fact that you have a timetstamp in your table as well.  If the user wants to filter a specific log by both timestamp and roll then if you were attempting to put all this information in the URL you would end up with something like `/logs/{id}/{roll}/{timestamp}` or maybe `/logs/{id}/{timestamp}/{roll}`, but you are already tying yourself in knots attempting to build a canonical URL where there is no obvious hierarchy.  Compare this to `/logs/{id}?roll=x&timestamp=y`, where it is very clear what you are attempting to obtain (a single log) and how you are filtering it (by roll and timestamp).  This also allows you to alter your query parameters in various ways, for example perhaps the `roll` parameter could be `!guest`, without affecting the resource URL.

By the way, it's role not roll, but stuck to roll in the explanation above to avoid confusion.

Comment: hehehehe.. oooh sorry for misspell it.. my english is bad.. hehehehe

thanks.. so the problem is clear now..